# WP7 WebBrowser's transparent background (workaround)

Tags: windows-phone-7, background, web-controls

It's not possible to set transparent background for WebBrowser of WP7. To make impression of transparent background I want to do the following workaround. I want:

1. To find a position and size of WebBrowser on the page.
2. To get page's background image.
3. Crop it with values what I found on step 1.
4. To save result in IsolatedStorage
5. To parse HTML and place  `<body background="RESULTBACKGROUND">`
6. `MyWebBrowser.NavigateToString(NewHtmlString);`

I think this should be a workaround of transparent background and should work.

For now I am trying just to place any .jpg image (let's say `test.jpg`) on step 5. 
But fail. I have "Build Action" property of file set to "Content". It is placed in the root of the project. And `<body background="test.jpg">` not working. Back of the WebBrowser is still white.

What I am doing wrong?

---

UPD:
Step 5 is solved.

2Claus: No! Not only from web. I saved both html file and image file to IsolatedStorage and WebBrowser can show image as a backgroud.

Now the problem is that background cannot be fixed. I tried many differrent things with styles. I also tried to add a fixed div behind my text. Nothing works. The picture is always scrolling with a text. I tried to add onscroll event and pass it scrolled value to move the div in an opposite direction, but div is glued to the page :(

Any ideas?

Comment: are you talking about the *WebBrowser* control? Windows Phone don't have a *WebControl*, that's ASP.NET WebForms.

Answer (score 2):

So assuming you're talking about the *WebBrowser* control, you're forgetting that the HTML only can refer to urls on the world wide web.

So either you need to host your background images on a website, or you need to inject a CSS style that sets the background to either white or black (the two default background-colours of the platform).

Answer (score 0):

For WebBrowser, You don't actually have to save it to the ISO to make changes on the page. You can load it navigate to it normally, and then use InvokeScript to make the changes via custom JS code. It can be a little tricky though, as you will probably need to heavily rely on the eval and stringization. The problem mentioned by Claus is still there - but you need to do some experiments. With the Mango release and SDK 7.1+, the platform support IsoltatedStorage imagesources in the form of is://path/file - maybe - maybe - maybe squared - the webbrowser's renderer udnerstands them too - then setting your bkg's url to such would work. I doubt though, as it could be seen as some minor security breach, etc

Comment: correction - the url scheme was not is:// but isostore:/ - but still, the WB does not understand it. Also, playing around with CSS's feature of rgba colors (ie. body.background=rgba(0,0,0,0)) - cause *very* ugly glitches, like digital noise and ghost-dumps from some framebuffers.. actually this looks quite funny:)

Answer (score 0):

I now bumped into the same background fixed image problem. For someone wandering here I solved it placing content into a fixed-height container (div) therefore the container contents is being scrolled and not the html page, leaving background picture "fixed".

```
body 
{ 
    background-image:url('...'); 
    background-position:-20px -150px; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-attachment:fixed; 
}
div
{
    height:300px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Of course background-position and div height is set specifically for a WebBrowser position in page and it's size.